# How to make mouse events only apply to outer DIV?

Tags: javascript, mouseevent

How do I make this work:

```
<div onclick="alert('You clicked me!')" style="background:lightblue;display:inline-block;padding:20px">
    <textarea rows="5" cols="50">You can click and select text here normally, but I don't register mouse events from the DIV behind me!</textarea>
    <div id="inner" style="background:lightgreen">Same here. I want my own mouse events - not the ones from #inner.</div>
</div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: You need to check the source of the event.

Comment: How do you check the source of the event? Can this be done inline (even if not recommended)? Is there a way to simply tell an element not to inherent events from its parent?

Comment: The TEXTAREA doesn't register mouse events from the DIV behind it? What does that mean? The #inner DIV wants its own mouse events - not the ones from #inner? What does that mean? Provide further information in your question.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure about this, but an event is bubbled from inside out, so an event handler in the parent will receive event from its descendants also. I might be wrong, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you want this:

```
<div onclick="if (event.target === this) alert('You clicked me!')">
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/UZtag/1/

So, the alert does *not* pop up if the TEXTAREA or #inner DIV is clicked, but only if the outer DIV is clicked directly.